# Can we write an ternary operator without a return value

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have an **Ternary Operator** in my Code and I Don't want to return any value from that **Ternary operator** ...

Can i write a **Ternary operator** with return value as **void** ...

Example :

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
```

Can i write as

```
(a<b ? a+=b : a-=b);
```

It's Showing an error like

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

Thank You ...

Comment: But why? Operators are for computations, statements for flow control.

Comment: you cant, you need to reference what you got on that code of yours. 

alternative, since you want to show the changes in `a` try this `a= a<b? a+=b : a-=b;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can i write a Ternary operator with return value as void

No, you can't.

The thing you can do is:

```
a = a<b ? a+b : a-b;
```

Or even:

```
a += a<b ? b : -b;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the ternary operator is itself an *expression* so it must evaluate to something. `a += b;` is a *statement* to putting it in a ternary does not make grammatical sense.

Either

1. write `a += a < b ? b : -b;`

or

2. Use `if`, `else` in the obvious way.

In engineering code, (1) is quite idiomatic.